# GVim - Python Jedi glitches

Tags: jedi-vim

While using the amazing Python Jedi plugin from GVim, I have started noticing some odd behavior with function completion tips popup (not the autocomplete as far as I can tell).

Firstly, while the function argument helper popup is visible, GVim input becomes laggy, even for builtin functions and standard types. Once the popup is closed, lag disappears. Autocomplete seems to work just fine on all levels, this lag seems to only apply to the function helper.

Secondly, I recently had a case where a popup became **frozen** in the buffer, even after it should have closed, and actually replaced the contents of the buffer at that location in the file. I finished the function I was working on, and then used `:/__init` to jump cursor location. My window scrolled down, but apparently the original function popup didn't clear, and become a fixture in my text.

When I saved the file, that line was replaced with the popup contents (obviously threw an Exception when python tried to execute that line). Going back to that location in the file, reactivating that function help popup and then closing it again fixed the *frozen* popup text.

Are these problems related?

Is this an aggressive configuration setting that I should change. Honestly those popups are a bit too aggressive for my liking sometimes, so how do I disable/hotkey-bind them in the configuration?

---

I have only experienced this behavior in GVim. Maybe it happens in console vim, but I have not tried to reproduce the situation, so I don't know.

GVim circumstances:

- 7 tabs open
- each tab usually has two vertical windows
- each window is usually a separate python module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a multitude of issues about this on jedi-vim's issue tracker: https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/issues/217. The whole lag situation is slowly getting better.

One of the easiest solutions is to just disable call signatures:

```
g:jedi#show_call_signatures = "0"
```

As of now ([I just merged that](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi-vim/pull/315)), there's another way of displaying call signatures:

> The call signatures can be displayed as a pop-up in the buffer (set to
>   1, the default), which has the advantage of being easier to refer to,
>   or in Vim's command line aligned with the function call (set to 2),
>   which can improve the integrity of Vim's undo history.

You could try if you like this better (but you have to update jedi-vim):

```
g:jedi#show_call_signatures = "2"
```

Comment: I do like the command line option. I know the lag has part to do with the modules I use (kivy), so I probably deserve some of it.